# Traffic Shaping and MQTT

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

There are two MQTT Brokers, the connection between them should enable traffic shaping. 
Broker A has multiple clients who publish data, Broker B has multiple subscriptions.

Is there a possibility to enable traffic shaping on the connection to ensure that very publisher hast a minimum of granted bandwidth on the connection to broker B?

This scenario is implemented using the Mosquitto MQTT broker with the broker-bridge feature to ensure every MQTT message will be send only once over the connection between broker A and B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because there is no information about who published the message included in the message header, only the topic and any retained flags.

The bridge between the 2 brokers is exactly the same sort of connection as between the a normal client and the broker, it looks to the remote broker just like any other client connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the last option is something like QoS on the application layer, but this is clearly an overkill for this.

Comment: You can set the QOS on the bridge subscriptions so you can enforce QOS 2 between the 2 brokers